# Run my projet to android device In titanium Studio

Tags: android, titanium, device

I work with titanium studio version 3.0.3

When I run my project into Android device, I got the errors:

```
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 287ms
```

It can not detect my device.

I installed the USB driver for sumsung and i configure Android device by Enable Unknown sources and Enable USB debugging.

In my eclipse IDE, I can detect my device and run my projects without probleme.

Can I give me some help, how can I deploying my projet to android device In titanium Studio

thanks :)

Comment: A work around, build app from cli using `ti build -p android -b`, then install app in device using `adb install -r build/android/bin/PROJECT_NAME.apk`. Be sure to be at root of your project.

Comment: Did you configure Android properly on your system? You can verify that on Dashboard page of TiStudio

Answer (score 0):

I use the following little script to launch the app on my device:

`$SN` variable defines the id of the device. You can get it by running `adb devices`

```
ti build -p android --build-only;
adb -s $SN uninstall com.example;
adb -s $SN install build/android/bin/applicationName.apk ;
adb -s $SN shell am start com.example/com.example.ActivityName
```

If you want to keep your application data in place, you should do the following:

```
adb -s $SN install build/android/bin/applicationName.apk ;
```

I'm assuming you have configured your PATH correctly.
Launch the script from your application folder. 
You will have to change `com.example` and `com.example.ActivityName` to match your configuration.

Comment: when I lauche my project with the command ti build -p android --build-only from my application folder it give me this errors:

[DEBUG] No project level plugins to load [DEBUG] Loaded plugin hooks: [DEBUG] C:\Users\FAC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\hooks\tisdk3fixes .js [DEBUG] 

 Is there any configurations that I forget ?